# Working with scientific notation in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, scientific-notation

I have a table with data in scientific notation (string).  How can I make this a usable figure in Netezza (not a string)?

```
select * from 
(
select '1.4545615464654E-14' as text_column
union 
select '1.7891561464654E-14' 
) foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you can actually cast these strings:

```
select cast(foo.text_column as numeric(15,15) )
from 
(
select '1.4545615464654E-14' as text_column
union 
select '1.7891561464654E-14' 
) foo
```